# Why does my program only output a correct number when one input is filled out, but output incorrect results if anymore inputs are filled out?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My program calculates a student's GPA, but it only accurately outputs a GPA if one input is filled out. Once any other inputs are filled out, the program outputs wildly inaccurate numbers. How can I fix this?

**The JavaScript:**

```js
function computeGPA() {
  var aPlus = document.getElementById("aPlus").value;
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var aMinus = document.getElementById("aMinus").value;
  var bPlus = document.getElementById("bPlus").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var bMinus = document.getElementById("bMinus").value;
  var cPlus = document.getElementById("cPlus").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var cMinus = document.getElementById("cMinus").value;
  var dPlus = document.getElementById("dPlus").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
  var dMinus = document.getElementById("dMinus").value;
  var f = document.getElementById("f").value;
  var og = ((aPlus*4)+(a*4)+(aMinus*3.7)+(bPlus*3.3)+(b*3)+(bMinus*2.7)+(cPlus*2.3)+(c*2)+(cMinus*1.7)+(dPlus*1.3)+(d*1)+(dMinus*.7))/((aPlus)+(a)+(aMinus)+(bPlus)+(b)+(bMinus)+(cPlus)+(c)+(cMinus)+(dPlus)+(d)+(dMinus))

  var prettyOg = og.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("og").innerHTML = "GPA: " + prettyOg;
}
```

**The HTML body:**

```html
<h1> Overall Grade Calculator</h1>

<p>Number of A+: <input id="aPlus" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of A: <input id="a" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of A-: <input id="aMinus" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of B+: <input id="bPlus" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of B: <input id="b" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of B-: <input id="bMinus" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of C+: <input id="cPlus" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of C: <input id="c" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of C-: <input id="cMinus" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of D+: <input id="dPlus" min="0" max="100"></input></p>
<p>Number of D: <input id="d" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of D-: <input id="dMinus" min="0" max="120"></input></p>
<p>Number of F: <input id="f" min="0" max="120"
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="computeGPA()">Submit</button>
<h2 id="og"></h2>
```

Comment: kindly put effort to indent your code properly

Answer (score 0):

Since `+` operator used for concatenation as well as addition. Input box will provide `string` values  so it's an ambiguous operation. To avoid this use `parseInt()` for addition operation.

Have a look at following example

```js
let a = '3';
let b = '5';

const result = a + b;
console.log('Result without parsing', result);
const resultWithParse = parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
console.log('Result after parsing', resultWithParse);
```